# ASP to Java/JSP

Tags: java, asp.net, jsp, syntax

So i'm a little bit new to asp, I'm working on converting a form from ASP to JSP/Java.

I'm working on the error section and I'm a little bit lost.

There is more to the code but I figured that this little snippet will do, well hopefully someone will know and point me in the right direction.

I'm stuck at the part where it starts with Set GetBase

```
Private Sub CreateRecordset()
    On Error Resume Next
    Set con_currency_sdo = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    con_currency_sdo.ConnectionTimeout = con_currency_sdo_ConnectionTimeout
    con_currency_sdo.CommandTimeout = con_currency_sdo_CommandTimeout
    con_currency_sdo.Open con_currency_sdo_ConnectionString, con_currency_sdo_RuntimeUserName, con_currency_sdo_RuntimePassword


    Set cmdTemp = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmdTemp.CommandText = "SELECT BLMBG_CURR_CODE,BLMBG_CURR_NAME" & _
        " FROM AON_CURRENCY_SDO" & _
        " ORDER BY BLMBG_CURR_NAME;"
    cmdTemp.CommandType = 1
    Set cmdTemp.ActiveConnection = con_currency_sdo

    Set GetBase = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    GetBase.Open cmdTemp, , 0, 1
    On Error Resume Next
    If GetBase.BOF And GetBase.EOF Then fEmptyRecordset = True
    On Error Goto 0
    If Err Then fEmptyRecordset = True
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Reading from the database in Java is completely different. You won't use anything like GetBase or Server.CreateObject...does that answer the question?

Comment: Yeah I knew that, It's just the syntax and markup are new to me I Haven't really worked with ASP before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear from your question whether your background is ASP or Java.  Here's some Java code which does roughly the same thing as the code above ... which is not much, it's just a fragment.

```
public class ConCurrencySdo {
  public String ConnectionString,RuntimeUser,RuntimePassword;
  public Connection con;
  public ResultSet GetBase;

  public void CreateRecordset() throws Exception {
    con = Drivermanager.getConnection(ConnectionString,RuntimeUser,RuntimePassword);
    PreparedStatement cmdTemp = con.prepareStatement("SELECT BLMBG_CURR_CODE,BLMBG_CURR_NAME" 
      + " FROM AON_CURRENCY_SDO" + " ORDER BY BLMBG_CURR_NAME");
    GetBase = cmdTemp.executeQuery();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you David, hopefully this will point me in the right direction. I'm new to both, I'm just more familiar with Java then ASP.